# Excel - Add cell value from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets

In the first sheet I have

**Names** and **Countries**

and in the another sheet I have **Countries** and **Countries_id**

I want to add all "Countries_id" into the first sheet into the appropriate cell

*Example*

Sheet_one : Names and Countries

```
Name   Country
Tomy   En 
Aleks  Fr
Jack   En
Monica Fr
```

Sheet_two : Countries with id

```
Country   id
En       1
Fr       2
```

**Result**:

```
Name   Country  Country_id
Tomy   En         1
Aleks  Fr         2 
Jack   En         1
Monica Fr         2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple VLOOKUP.

If we say that sheet 1 starts in cell A1, then add the following formula in C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3,2,FALSE)
```

This says "look up the value found in B2 in the first column of the range on sheet 2 that goes from A2 to B3. When you find an exact match ("false"), return the corresponding value from column 2.

Copy this to all cells under `Country_id` and you're done.

Note - you need the `$` signs for the `$A$2:$B$3` since that reference is ABSOLUTE - as you copy down, you want to refer to the same range (could be done by naming the range if you wanted). The `B2` value is RELATIVE, so that when you copy down, you get C2, D2, etc.

Comment: There was problem with the comma, I replaced it with ; and it worked

=VLOOKUP(B2;Sheet2!$A$2:$B$3;2;FALSE)


maybe it's because I use Ms Exel 2007.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The `;` vs `,` depends on your localization - for example German Excel needs the `;`. I think it is true for any locale where they use the comma as a decimal marker since you cannot know if `12,15` is a list of two parameters, or a single parameter meaning 12 and 15 hundredths. Glad you were able to figure it out!